# Como generar otro contenedor al hacer click en un boton

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buenas tardes realicé un To do list con js css y html donde se pueden eliminar agregar tareas a hacer. Mi pregunta es la siguiente, es posible que el clickear en un botón generar una lista completamente nueva alado de la que ya tengo? Mi idea es que la webapp sea parecido a trello donde podría tener una primera lista con un titulo otra con otro titulo y asi.

index.html:
Lo que quiero realizar es que si yo clickeo en este boton me genere otra lista nueva alado de la que ya tengo.

```
<div class="title">
        <h1>Add new list</h1>
        <button class="newList">Add new To Do List</button>
    </div>
```

La lista nueva tendría que ser como esta:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <header>To do</header>
        <div class="inputField">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add new item">
            <button><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
        <ul class="todoList">
            
            
        </ul>
        <div class="footer">
            <span>You have <span class="pendingNumb"></span> items pending</span>
            <button>Clear All</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Si alguien sabe hacerlo y me quiere dar una idea como para que yo pueda comenzar a resolverlo me vendría bien.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript tiene una funcion `createElement(tagName, [options])` que lo que hace es crear un nuevo elemento, luego podemos hacer lo que queramo.

```js
let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
```

Sin embargo al querer crear demasiados elementos esto podria resultar dificil y no legible, por eso existen los `template-string` con los cuales podremos crear plantillas *html* y luego instaertarlas en el **DOM**

Tu problema se resolveria de esta forma

```js
const temp = `
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>To do</header>
    <div class="inputField">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add new item">
        <button><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
    <ul class="todoList">
                       
    </ul>
    <div class="footer">
        <span>You have <span class="pendingNumb"></span> items pending</span>
        <button>Clear All</button>
    </div>
</div>
`
//evento del click
//primero agregas el id="newList" al boton
let btn = document.getElementById("newList")

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //seleccionas donde lo vas a insertar
    let contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor")
    contenedor.innerHTML = temp
})
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>Add new list</h1>
  <button id = "newList" class="newList">Add new To Do List</button>
</div>

<div id="contenedor">
</div>
```

Si quieres agregar valores o cosas dinámicas dentro del template lo puedes hacer, para esos usas `${varName}`

```js
let person = "Christian"
const temp = `
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>To do</header>
        <div class="inputField">
            <input type="text" placeholder="${person} Add new item">
            <button><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
        ....
    </div>            
    `
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto dependería de qué exactamente querés hacer.
¿Dónde está ubicado tu **ul class="todoList"** ; en el HTML o externo?
Si es un solo archivo externo, se puede crear con JavaScript, dentro de **.js** de la siguiente manera:

```
let button = document.querySelector('.newList');
let buttonNuevo = document.querySelector('ul');

// Aquí se inserta el HTML entre las comillas especial: ``
const nuevo = `
<h1>Hola </h1>
`;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
 buttonNuevo.innerHTML = nuevo;  
}
```

Al hacer click al botón .newList, el HTML en **nuevo** se carga dentro de **ul class="todoList"**.

Espero que te sirva: solo crea tu lista HTML dentro de las comillas especial en JavaScript

Comment: las *comillas especiales* se llaman backticks