# Como concatenar un div en html con js

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas tardes quería saber como concatenar un bloque html que contiene un div con listas y botones dentro al hacer click en un boton. Tengo entendido que se puede hacer con templeate strings pero no se bien como hacerlo.

scripts.js:
Tengo esta variable con mi bloque de html dentro

```
miDiv = `<header>To do</header>
        <div class="inputField">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add new item">
            <button><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
        <ul class="todoList">
            
            
        </ul>
        <div class="footer">
            <span>You have <span class="pendingNumb"></span> items pending</span>
            <button>Clear All</button>
        </div>`
```

index.html:
Lo que me gustaría hacer es que al clickear en el boton con id "newList" se agregue el contenido de la variable miDiv dentro del div con class wrapper.

```
<div class="title">
        <h1>Add new list</h1>
        <button class="newList" id="newList">Add new To Do List</button>
    </div>
    

    <div class="wrapper">
        
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Cabe aclarar que el div que quiero agregar tiene funciones y lógica para agregar otros elementos dentro, entonces cuando concateno el contenedor, las demas funciones dejan de funcionarme como por ejemplo la siguiente:

scrip.js:

```
function showTask(){
    let getLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("New Todo");
    if(getLocalStorage == null){
        listArr = [];

    } else {
        listArr = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage); //Transformar un json string en un objeto de js
    }
    const pendingNumb = document.querySelector(".pendingNumb");
    
    pendingNumb.textContent = listArr.length;
    
    if (listArr.length > 0){
        deleteAllBtn.classList.add("active");
    } else {
        deleteAllBtn.classList.remove("active");
    }

    let newLiTag = '';
    listArr.forEach((element, index) =>{
        newLiTag += `<li> ${element} <span onclick="deleteTask((${index}))";><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span></li>`; //Concateno un li a la lista
    });
    todoList.innerHTML = newLiTag;
    inputBox.value = ''; //Reseteo el texto que le pase al To do
}
```

Esta función lo que hace es agregar tareas al to do list y funciona perfectamente, pero si concateno el div del principio, estas funciones dejan de funcionar.

Comment: para agregar un template-string a un elemento se unsa `elemento.innerHTML = template`

Comment: Esto ya te lo respondí [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/452998/183782)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como generar otro contenedor al hacer click en un boton](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/452983/como-generar-otro-contenedor-al-hacer-click-en-un-boton)

Comment: @Christian si y me fue de gran ayuda, me había olvidado de editar esta pregunta para que puedan entender el inconveniente que estoy teniendo.

Comment: si la respuesta te sirvio acpetala, esto sera de ayuda para otras personas con el mismo problema en un futuro

Comment: para que tu pregunta se entienda mejor, añade un enlace a la pregunta anterior, esto para tenga un contexto mas claro

Comment: @Christian okey, pero pudiste entender mi inconveniente que estoy teniendo ahora? Si es asi me vendría bien una ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Un poco, creo. Si no me equivoco tu proble esta que, al momento de agregar los divs, ya no realizan su funcion, cierto?

Comment: @Christian exactamente, por ejemplo dentro de ese div yo tengo una funcion que al clickear en el boton de + que tiene el icon fa-plus se agregue una tarea nueva y eso funcionaba, tambien otra funcion para eliminar tareas, pero ahora que saque el bloque del div del html y directamente lo estoy concatenando desde javascript, esas funciones dejan de funcionar.

Comment: Si mas no me equivoco el problema seria al seleccionar los elementos por su clase con `const pendingNumb = document.querySelector(".pendingNumb");` agrega un elemento y luego haz un `console.log(pendingNumb )` y mira lo que te retorna :), *aqui vine chido*

Answer (score 0):

Para colocar el código de tu variable **miDiv**, lo primero sería identificar en donde lo quieres colocar. Como mencionas, lo quieres colocar en el interior de tu
**div class="wrapper"**. Para ello, vamos a añadirle un atributo **id** a ese div:

```
div class="wrapper" id="colocarDentro"
```

Además también tendrás que asignarle un id a tu boton, para que posteriormente en nuestro javascript podamos identificarlo:

```
<button id="miBoton">Anyadir</button>
```

Posteriormente, en el código JavaScript deberás obtener dicho div. Para ello explicaremos lo siguiente:

**document.getElementById()**: Nos permite obtener una etiqueta de nuestro html.

**innerHTML**: Nos permite acceder al contenido HTML que tiene dentro.

Recordando que a cada elemento le asignaste un id, en nuestro javaScript tendremos el siguiente código:

```
let elBoton = document.getElementById('miBoton');

elBoton.onclick = function(){
    let elDvi = document.getElementById('colocarDentro');
    let contenido = "<b>Hola gente</b>";
    elDvi.innerHTML = elDvi.innerHTML + contenido;
}
```

Lo primero que haremos será identificar ese botón con el uso de *document.getElementById()*. A esa variable le asignaremos un evento onclick, esto quiere decir, cuando el usuario seleccione el botón se ejecutará el código en su interior.

El código del interior obtendrá el div al cual quieras añadirte un contenido. Luego, en mi caso, he creado una variable contenido (pero tu usaras tu variable **miDiv**).
Por último concatenamos todo el html que ya había dentro del div y le asignamos de nuevo mas codigo HTML con uso de *innerHTML*

Edit: Recuerda añadir ese archivo javascript de esta forma:

```
<script src="./ELARCHIVO.js" defer></script>
```

Tienes que esperar a que el html cargue completamente o sino no encontrará las etiquetas htmml, por eso hago uso del **defer**. Otra opción es colocar esta etiqueta al final del body.

Comment: no creo que sea la solucion, ya que la pregunta dice que al crear un nuevo elemento sus funciones y/o eventos ya no le funcionan, y esto es debido a que los selecciona con un `querySelector()` lo que devuelve un *HTMLCollection* el cual tendra que recorrer. Puedes hacer una mejor respuesta en base a lo que dije, de lo contrario lo hare yopi. :)